# Combine 2 lists of dict in one list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.7

In python3 I have 2 lists:

```
listA = [{'aString': 'someone', 'aNumber': 123}]
listB = [{'anotherNumber': 456}]
```

How do I combine them into 1 single list which looks like this?

```
listC = [{'aString': 'someone', 'aNumber': 123, 'anotherNumber': 456}]
```

If I use,

```
listC = listA + listB
```

I get:

```
listC = [{'aString': 'someone', 'aNumber': 123}, {'anotherNumber': 456}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: you don't actually look for merging lists but merging dictionaries in lists. you can merge dictionaries with dict.update().

Comment: you have two list of dicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the two lists into the dict constructor and then unpack the two dicts into one:

```
[{**dict(*listA), **dict(*listB)}]
```

Comment: just to mention... it's only going to work in python 3

Comment: Right (generic unpacking is available since Python 3.5 to be precise). The OP does tag the question with python-3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
listC = dict(listA .items() + listB.items())
```

Comment: his answer came in Low Quality posts in SO since its code only answer.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users